# Updating XML from select boxes and vice versa using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a series of select boxes in a file like such:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Lane 1:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="lane1Status">
            <option value="closed">Closed</option>
            <option value="cue">Cue</option>
            <option value="registration">Registration</option>
            <option value="finAid" selected>Financial Aid & Scholarships</option>
            <option value="admisssions">Admissions</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

There are 8 separate "lanes" (this is for student line queing). When a user changes the selection in any of those boxes and hits submit, it needs to update that "lane" in an xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<update>
<Lane1Status>registration</Lane1Status>
<Lane2Status>registration</Lane2Status>
<Lane3Status>registration</Lane2Status>
<Lane4Status>registration</Lane2Status>
<Lane5Status>registration</Lane2Status>
<Lane6Status>registration</Lane2Status>
<Lane7Status>registration</Lane2Status>
<Lane8Status>registration</Lane2Status>
</update>
```

When that value is set, it needs to in turn be the default selection for that particular lane when the user pulls up the page. So if Lane1Status is updated to "closed", whenever a user opens up the form, that lane needs to be set to closed by default.

Comment: It is made up on the fly. I have very little experience with xml. Thank you for the help. That does look much better, and makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's make sure we're clear on the XML file that contains our data. This is what it should look like:

```
   <?xml  version="1.0" ?>
   <lanes>
       <lane>
           <order>1</order>
           <status>registration</status>
       </lane>
       <lane>
           <order>2</order>
           <status>registration</status>
       </lane>
       <lane>
           <order>3</order>
           <status>registration</status>
       </lane>
       <lane>
           <order>4</order>
           <status>registration</status>
       </lane>
       <lane>
           <order>5</order>
           <status>registration</status>
       </lane>
   </lanes>
```

Next, we need to think about how we're going to load this information onto the page by using PHP. Therefore, we need to know WHERE this XML file is located and know that if you ever move it or change the name of the file, you will need to change your PHP code. Additionally, there is no need to setup separate pages to handle all of the updating. So, let's handle it all on the same page - a file we'll call myProcess.php

First, we need create our globals and check if there is POST data to handle:

```
     <?php
     $file = "myFile.xml";
     $arrXml = array();
     $count = 5; // number of lanes

     if (count($_POST) > 0) {
             // we're returning to the page with
             // form data and need to update our XML
             updateXMLFile();
             unset($_POST);
     }

     // regardless we want to load the XML
     readXMLFile();
     ?>
```

Next, we need to setup our functions:

```
         function readXMLFile() {
         global $file;
         global $arrXml;
         global $count;

         $xmlStr = file_get_contents($file);
         $arrXml = xml2array($xmlStr);
     }

     function updateXMLFile() {
        global $file;
        global $arrXml;
        global $count;

        $string = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><lanes>';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count;$i++)
        {
            $string .= "<lane><order>$i</order>";
            $string .= "<status>".$_POST['lane'.$i.'status']."</status></lane>";
        }
        $string .= "</lanes>";

        $string = utf8_encode($string);
        file_put_contents($file, $string);
    }
```

Here's a great XML -> array function that can be found in the comments of the PHP documentation:

```
    function xml2array($xml){ 
        $opened = array(); 
        $opened[1] = 0; 
        $xml_parser = xml_parser_create(); 
        xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $xml, $xmlarray); 
        $array = array_shift($xmlarray); 
        unset($array["level"]); 
        unset($array["type"]); 
        $arrsize = sizeof($xmlarray); 
        for($j=0;$j<$arrsize;$j++){ 
           $val = $xmlarray[$j]; 
           switch($val["type"]){ 
               case "open": 
                  $opened[$val["level"]]=0; 
               case "complete": 
                  $index = ""; 
                  for($i = 1; $i < ($val["level"]); $i++) 
                      $index .= "[" . $opened[$i] . "]"; 
                  $path = explode('][', substr($index, 1, -1)); 
                  $value = &$array; 
                  foreach($path as $segment) 
                     $value = &$value[$segment]; 
                  $value = $val; 
                  unset($value["level"]); 
                  unset($value["type"]); 
                  if($val["type"] == "complete") 
                    $opened[$val["level"]-1]++; 
                  break; 
              case "close": 
                  $opened[$val["level"]-1]++; 
                  unset($opened[$val["level"]]); 
                  break; 
           } 
       } 
       return $array; 
   }
```

Now, we have everything setup to build our form. I assume you know how to create an HTML page, so I'll just focus on the form portion.

```
    <form name="myForm" method="POST" action"myProcess.php">
    <?php
        for($i = 1;$i <= $count;$i++)
        {
            echo '<label for="lane'.$i.'status">Lane '.$i.': </label>';
            echo '<select name="lane'.$i.'status">';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "closed")
                echo '<option value="closed" selected="selected">Closed</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="closed">Closed</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "cue")
                echo '<option value="cue" selected="selected">Cue</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="cue">Cue</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "registration")
                echo '<option value="registration" selected="selected">Registration</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="registration">Registration</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "finAid")
                echo '<option value="finAid" selected="selected">Financial Aid & Scholarships</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="finAid">Financial Aid & Scholarships</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "admissions")
                echo '<option value="admissions" selected="selected">Admissions</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="admissions">Admissions</option>';            
            echo '</select>';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

So, putting all of that together, here is what myProcess.php looks like:

```
    <?php
     $file = "myFile.xml";
     $arrXml = array();
     $count = 5; // number of lanes

     if (count($_POST) > 0) {
             // we're returning to the page with
             // form data and need to update our XML
             updateXMLFile();
             unset($_POST);
     }

     // regardless we want to load the XML
     readXMLFile();

     function readXMLFile() {
         global $file;
         global $arrXml;
         global $count;

         $xmlStr = file_get_contents($file);
         $arrXml = xml2array($xmlStr);
     }

     function updateXMLFile() {
        global $file;
        global $arrXml;
        global $count;

        $string = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><lanes>';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count;$i++)
        {
            $string .= "<lane><order>$i</order>";
            $string .= "<status>".$_POST['lane'.$i.'status']."</status></lane>";
        }
        $string .= "</lanes>";

        $string = utf8_encode($string);
        file_put_contents($file, $string);
    }

    function xml2array($xml){ 
        $opened = array(); 
        $opened[1] = 0; 
        $xml_parser = xml_parser_create(); 
        xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $xml, $xmlarray); 
        $array = array_shift($xmlarray); 
        unset($array["level"]); 
        unset($array["type"]); 
        $arrsize = sizeof($xmlarray); 
        for($j=0;$j<$arrsize;$j++){ 
           $val = $xmlarray[$j]; 
           switch($val["type"]){ 
               case "open": 
                  $opened[$val["level"]]=0; 
               case "complete": 
                  $index = ""; 
                  for($i = 1; $i < ($val["level"]); $i++) 
                      $index .= "[" . $opened[$i] . "]"; 
                  $path = explode('][', substr($index, 1, -1)); 
                  $value = &$array; 
                  foreach($path as $segment) 
                     $value = &$value[$segment]; 
                  $value = $val; 
                  unset($value["level"]); 
                  unset($value["type"]); 
                  if($val["type"] == "complete") 
                    $opened[$val["level"]-1]++; 
                  break; 
              case "close": 
                  $opened[$val["level"]-1]++; 
                  unset($opened[$val["level"]]); 
                  break; 
           } 
       } 
       return $array; 
    } 

    ?>

    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" method="POST" action"myProcess.php">
    <?php
        for($i = 1;$i <= $count;$i++)
        {
            echo '<label for="lane'.$i.'status">Lane '.$i.': </label>';
            echo '<select name="lane'.$i.'status">';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "closed")
                echo '<option value="closed" selected="selected">Closed</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="closed">Closed</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "cue")
                echo '<option value="cue" selected="selected">Cue</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="cue">Cue</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "registration")
                echo '<option value="registration" selected="selected">Registration</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="registration">Registration</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "finAid")
                echo '<option value="finAid" selected="selected">Financial Aid & Scholarships</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="finAid">Financial Aid & Scholarships</option>';
            if ($arrXml[$i-1][1]['value'] == "admissions")
                echo '<option value="admissions" selected="selected">Admissions</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="admissions">Admissions</option>';            
            echo '</select>';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much Ally. That is a very well thought out way of handling this.